# jQuery dataTables: Cannot read property 'sSortDataType' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I'm trying to use `jQuery.dataTables.js` on my web page, but I got this error when starting the page; I'm new to scripting, especially in this framework.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sSortDataType' of undefined

I also tried the solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16294902/jquery-datatables-sort-multiple-tables), but it didn't work for me.

This is some of my script:

```
var oTable = $('#table').dataTable({
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"
});
oTable.fnSort([[5, "desc"]]);
oTable.fnSetColumnVis(5, false);
```

and this is my sample table:

```
<table class="display" class="table" id="table" style="width:100%;text-align: center ">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th style="width: 10%"><label>PR No.</label></th>
        <th style="width: 30%"><label>Requesting Department</label></th>
        <th style="width: 20%"><label>Assessed By</label></th>
        <th style="width: 20%"><label>Noted By</label></th>
        <th style="width: 20%"><label>Status</label></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>11111</td>
        <td>IT</td>
        <td>fufu</td>
        <td>fufu</td>
        <td>fufu</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: I could not replicate the problem. Please check this plunker and let me know
https://plnkr.co/edit/Rt3gtFe7gXLNvhnncbjb?p=preview

Comment: I am not using <script src = "https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script> 
instead use this datatables.
<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

Comment: i think it is the same script. Instead of downloading and storing it in local i am using online version

Comment: sorry, I get that Uncaught TypeError using chrome. but when I look using mozilla I get this: TypeError: oSettings.aoColumns[iColumn] is undefined

Comment: @user2181397 I dont know if that is the same, because you used datatables.min.js, while I am using datatables.js??

Comment: a .min file is the minified version of a file. It is used to reduce application load time

Comment: @user2181397 actually I using dynamic table data for that and I dont know it take effect the error I get. I am using jstl and mvc java.

Comment: @user2181397, thank you for wonderful info. Ill take note of that.